# XTightvnc font path error

Tags: raspbian

I try to run vncserver on Raspberry Pi but this error is shown:

```
Couldn’t start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn’t start Xtightvnc process.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar error when trying to install the tightvncserver. The comment here about the host name helped to fix my problem.

I had changed the default pi host name in raspi-config, but it would appear that the standard install for tightvncserver sticks with the default hostname of "pi". I changed my pi hostname back to pi in the raspi-config tool and the vncserver now works without the above reported errors.

This is the error I had.

```
~ $ tightvncserver
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the tightvncserver script.
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the default *hostname* (a.k.a. Computer name) is 'raspberry', and it is the default *username* (Thing located between screen/keyboard and chair) that is 'pi'?

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn’t start Xtightvnc process.

- Check your hostname and make sure this and /etc/hosts are the same.

`nano /etc/hostname
 nano /etc/hosts
 hostname`

> Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script

- Fonts are missing. Look in folder:

`ls /usr/share/fonts/X11/`

If you can't find them there either then simply install xfonts-base

`apt-get install  xfonts-base`